# Parallel processing a prime finder with openMP

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, primes

I am trying to construct a prime finder for a bit of C practice. I've got the algorithm down and I've done a bunch of optimisations to make it faster, I then decided to try to parallelize it because, hey why not! Turns out to be harder than I thought. I can either get all threads running the same process (with same args) or a single thread will run if I try and supply different args to each process. I really have no idea what I'm doing here but you can see some experimental values I'm using in this code:

```
// gcc -std=c99 -o multithread multithread.c -fopenmp -lm

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

int pf(unsigned int start, unsigned int limit, unsigned int q);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
printf("prime finder\n");

int j, slimits[4] = {1,10000000,20000000,30000000}, elimits[4] = {10000000,20000000,30000000,40000000};

double startTime = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel shared(slimits, elimits primes)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        primes += pf(slimits[j], elimits[j], atoi(argv[2]));
    }
}
printf("%d prime numbers found in %.2f seconds.\n\n", primes, omp_get_wtime() - startTime);
return 0;
}
```

I havn't included the pf function as it is quite large but it works on its own, it returns the number of primes found. Im sure the issue is here somewhere.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made at least one obvious (to me) and serious mistake.  You've declared `primes` shared and allowed all the threads in the program to update it.  You have, thereby, programmed a data race.  Nothing in OpenMP (nor in C if I recall correctly) guarantees that `+=` will be implemented atomically.  You haven't actually specified what the problem with your program is, or what the problems are, but this must surely be one of them.

I'll tell you how to fix this later but I think there is a more serious underlying design problem you should address first.  You seem to have decided that you would have 4 threads running and that you should divide the range of integers to test for primality into 4 and pass one chunk to each thread.  Sure, you can make that work but it's not a smart approach to using OpenMP.  Nor is it a smart approach to dividing the work of primality testing.

A smarter approach to OpenMP program design is to start off by making no assumptions about the number of threads that will be available to the executing program.  Design for any number of threads, do not design a program whose behaviour depends on the number of threads it gets at run-time.  Use OpenMP's facilities, specifically the `schedule` clause, to distribute the workload at run time.

Turning to primality testing. Draw, or at least think about, a scatter plot of points `(i,t(i))`, where `i` is an integer and `t(i)` is the time it takes to determine whether or not `i` is prime.  The pattern in this plot is about as difficult to discern as the pattern in the plot of the occurrence of primes in the integers.  In other words, the time to determine the primality of an integer is very unpredictable.  It does tend to rise as the integers increase (well, excluding large even integers which I'm sure your test doesn't consider anyway).

One implication of this unpredictability is that if you divide a range of integers into `N` sub-ranges and give one sub-range to each of `N` threads you are not giving the threads the same amount of work to do.  Indeed, in the range of integers `1..m` (any `m`) there is one integer which takes much longer to test than any other integer in the range, and this time is the irreducible minimum that your program will take.  A naive distribution of the range will produce a seriously unbalanced workload.

Here's what I think you should do to fix your program.

First, write a function which tests the primality of a single integer.  This will be the basic task for your computation.  Call this `is_prime`.  Next, study the `schedule` clause for the parallel `for` construct.  OpenMP provides a number of task scheduling options, I won't explain them here, you will find plenty of good documentation online.  Finally, study also the `reduction` clause; this provides the solution to the data race you have programmed.

Applying all this I suggest you change

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(slimits, elimits primes)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        primes += pf(slimits[j], elimits[j], atoi(argv[2]));
    }
}
```

to

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(slimits, elimits, max_int_to_test) 
{
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:primes) schedule (dynamic, 10)
    for (j = 3; j < max_int_to_test; j += 2)
    {
        primes += is_prime(j);
    }
}
```

With any luck my rudimentary C hasn't screwed up the syntax too much.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I should probably admit adding multithreading was an afterthought and, since im a totally noob programmer, I didnt really think the program though. I've now implemented it as a single isprime() function and have some fantastic multithreading going on which is reducing the processing by 30% already! I will read though the documentation now and try to cut that further. Thanks again!